# Where should I place a script in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, openpgp.js

I am very new to react/redux/node and I recently started learning them.

I am trying to write an application that would use OpenPGP.JS to provide encryption and decryption functions. While certain components within the application may need to call the script, which uses [OpenPGP.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs) library for encryption, I am not sure about where to put the script.

Edit: The following is the current tree structure.

```
├── LICENSE.MD
├── README.md
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── actions
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── components
│   │   └── app.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── reducers
│       └── index.js
├── style
│   └── style.css
├── test
│   ├── components
│   │   └── app_test.js
│   └── test_helper.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

[image: Workflow]

Comment: you can bundle it with app, you can include as script tag. depends

Comment: What is this script ? What are you trying to achieve ? Can you include the code of your application ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I updated the post with more details since I don't have any code written yet.

Comment: Why don't you just import it, i.e. import OpenPGP from './OpenPGP' in the component that you want to use it in

Comment: @linasmnew - A few reasons: 

1. I tried that but I get a warning message `This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.`

2. The script code may be called from multiple components.

3. The script is available via CDN and I would like to the hosted version from `https://cdnjs.com/libraries/openpgp`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add client JavaScript to your package.json and install them with npm or yarn. Your directory structure does not show where openpgp is located but it should be in node_modules (also not in your directory structure).

Since you're using webpack you can just install it with npm or yarn (as [documented](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs#getting-started)):

```
npm install --save openpgp
```

Then require it in your script:

```
require openpgp from "openpgp"
```

If webpack complains because the github repo points to dist/openpgp.js you could try to add a [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) in your webpack.config.js that points to the src directory instead of the dist.

Comment: Where do I write javascript code (wrapper/util functions for OpenPGP)?

Comment: @RahilParikh Where ever you'd like. You can put it in util or service and export the functions you want. Your action handlers can import that util or service functions. Or you import it in your main application and pass it as a dependency to an init function of your action handlers, that way it's easier to mock out for tests or replace with another module.